# Centering in a Vue component is offset but normal in a plain page

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I would like to center a value in a square, in a Vue component. The bare code works fine in a plain web page:

```css
#element {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 60pt;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#box {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <div id="box">
    18
  </div>
</div>
```

The same code put into a Vue component (`<temperature-outside>`, referenced below)

```
<template>
<div id="element">
  <div id="box">
     18
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// 
</script>

<style>
#element {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 60pt;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
#box {
  text-align: center; 
}
</style>
```

which is itself simply put in a plain HTML page (without extra styling)

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <temperature-outside></temperature-outside>
    </div>
</body>
```

displays as

[image]

**It is offset to the right and bottom.**

When looking at the element in DevTools, I see that the text itself is not centered in the box:

[image]

The same code in Codepen is centered correctly:

[image]

**What is the reason for this difference?**

Comment: What other CSS libraries are you using?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: nothing else, I do not add any other styling or libraries. I just bundle the component with `webpack` as it.

Comment: I [created a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6anzvc2/) from your code and could not reproduce this. There has to be some external, extenuating factor

Comment: The only thing I can suggest here is to check your doctype, make sure you have no browser plugins that might be affecting the output.  I tried a similar approach to @Ohgodwhy and wasn't able to see what you're seeing either.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I opened the page with my code on Firefox and it is OK. It must really be something with Chrome, or rather my Chrome. I will hunt this down and report back. Thanks for the help.